# Xamarin FontAwesome not working from code behind

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I am wondering if I am missing some thing here.

When using FontAwesome in xaml for iOS it works just fine like this:

```
<Button Text="&#xf075;" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="DarkRed" TextColor="White" FontSize="36">
    <Button.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="fa-regular-400.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" WinPhone="Assets/fa-regular-400.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
    </Button.FontFamily>
</Button>
```

But when doing this in the code behind for the page I do not get the icon but its unicode `&#xf075`;

Here is my code behind code:

```
var newBtn = new Button()
{

    Text = "&#xf11a;",
    HeightRequest = 100,
    BackgroundColor = Color.DarkRed,
    TextColor = Color.White,
    FontSize = 36

};

newBtn.FontFamily = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "Font Awesome 5 Free" : null;
```

Comment: try this `Text = ((char)0xf11a).ToString();`

Comment: Perfect, works just like the answer from Daniel P. Thanks :-)

Comment: Question though... If you have a license for FA-Pro how do I use that?

Comment: @Mansa- I have never used licences for FA. However you could go to FA support & sent them mail along with your queries. Or ask the same question here or on xamarin forums, you might get answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using from within C# code, you have to use it like this:

`Text = "\uf11a"`

Comment: This worked if I passed the value directly to the element, but if the value stored into variable than it doesn't work. How can I solve this ?

Comment: @AmirImam I had the same problem. Declaring the property static instead of const solved the issue