# Xamarin addind ToolbarItem in dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, font-awesome-4

I am new with Xamarin.

I am using Xamarin using font-awesome 4.7 version, I am trying to add a ToolbarItem in the code behind:

```
var toolBarItem = new ToolbarItem
{
    Icon = "&#xf053;",
}
```

In xaml file I can do something this:

```
<assets:Icon Text="&#xf053;" TextColor="#5DD046" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
```

But I need it to work in the code behind, can someone advise me how to go about it?

Comment: Try setting icon text without escaping `Text="\uf053"`

Comment: @shanranm can you please elaborate more.

Comment: Since you were able to get it working in Xaml, I'm assuming you've already written renderer for changing the toolbar item font (to font-awesome). Just set the `Text` property of `ToolbarItem` to the unicode value of the icon (in this case `\uf053`).

Answer (score 1):

From code behind you can do like this

```
Icon = "\uf053"
```

Or

```
Icon = ((char)0xf053).ToString();
```

Your original values is `"&#xf053;"`, so for all values the same rule applies to change.

Comment: Thank you but how do you indicate that I want it to be an icon and NOT a text?

Comment: We not need to know it. By the forms of string it is recognizing. Are you facing that conflict?

Comment: All I am getting is a marking for a icon (like a small square box with a x in the middle) but not the the actual font awesome icon I need

Comment: I think you need to set `FontFamily`. For `Toolbar` you need to use custom renderer to do so, which would be more complicated. I'll suggest you here to use icons. for more information visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274361/xamarin-fontawesome-not-working-from-code-behind

Comment: If I do Text = ((char)0xf053).ToString(), at lest I get the square box mentioned above but if I do Icon = ((char)0xf270).ToString(), I get nothing

Comment: @ML13 - I have updated my answer. Now I notice that it should have been `Icon` instead of `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a toolbar item but in order to appear, it has to be added to the page.
So in your page code you should call

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add(toolBarItem);
```

after creating the item.